# Javascript- passing variables to php page with window.location.href not working

Tags: javascript, php

Some part of js function :
nothig sent to database, and i've tested t1, t2 & t3 by alert, they're not empty, Any solutions, thanks.

```js
else{
    var t1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
    var t2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;
    var t3 = document.getElementById('t3').value;
    window.location.href = "b1.php?t1=" + t1+ "&t2=" + t2 + "&t3=" + t3 ;
    alert( 'success' ); 
  }
```

```html
//b1.php

<?php
  
        $email=$_GET["t1"];
    
 $img=$_GET["t2"];
 
        $target=$_GET["t3"];
 
        include("connection.php");
        $sql=mysql_query("insert into b1(email, img, target)
         values ('$email', '$img', '$target')");
   
   
?>

//connection.php

<?php
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db("banner");
?>
```

note : i use wampserver for testing

Comment: What does `$_GET` output for you?

Comment: try on  `window.location = "www.yourwebsite.com/b1.php?t1=" + t1+ "&t2=" + t2 + "&t3=" + t3 ;`

Comment: @king bia : As you are using `GET` method to pass data to your php page so you can properly see if the values are passed in the URL??? So are they passed or not??

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @ShahKhalid : Make sure to include `http://` also at the begining of the url or it will be considered a directory under your current domain link..!

Comment: @King bia : And just so you know what you can't use anything after a redirect as that's not gonna work so either you can add the `alert();` before your redirection or you should remove it then..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** The values are not submitted through `GET` Method..!

**Note** : First I checked the code in Chrome & then in Firefox.Strange thing was that the code was working perfect in Firefox while in chrome it wasn't working at all & was also not working in Internet Explorer etc..!

**Solution :** 
I then checked that as you may be submitting the values on a submit so you need to add an `event.preventDefault();` to your code..!

Here is the code which I tried and worked right away :

```
<form action="home.php" onsubmit="redirect(event)">
<input type="text" id="t1">
<input type="text" id="t2">
<input type="text" id="t3">
<input type="submit" >
</form>

<script>

function redirect() {

var t1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
          var t2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;
          var t3 = document.getElementById('t3').value;
          event.preventDefault();
          alert( 'success' ); 
          window.location.href = "b1.php?t1=" + t1+ "&t2=" + t2 + "&t3=" + t3 ;


}

</script>
```

Comment: If it's not the case so then update your question with your whole code that exactly how are you submitting these values even in the first place cuz you just shared an `else` part of the JS Code..!

Comment: You need to call the function as `onsubmit="redirect(event)"`. Some browsers don't provide `event` as a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar : Do you mean that's the reason why it was not working in the first place as It's working now without using event with the redirect function??

Comment: No, I mean you need to fix that for this answer to be correct.

Comment: Your code will work in some browsers, but not others.